# Storing a DATA from ajax to a JSON variable for later use

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I wrote this Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetAllCustomer()
    {
        CustomerList customer_list = new CustomerList();
        customer_list.Fill();
        using (DataTable dt = customer_list.Data)
        {
            customer_list = null;
            return Json(Utilities.GetTableRows(dt), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

and i wrote this Ajax JS script(this will populate to HTML table):

```
var tempTable;
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '@Url.Action("GetAllCustomer", "Customer")',
        success: function (data) {
            var table = document.getElementById("tblCustomer");
            $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                var row = table.insertRow(-1);

                var code = row.insertCell(0);
                var Name = row.insertCell(1);
                var CompanyName = row.insertCell(2);
                var PhoneNumer = row.insertCell(3);
                var Active = row.insertCell(4);

                code.innerHTML = item["code"];
                Name.innerHTML = item["customer_name"];
                CompanyName.innerHTML = item["company_name"];
                PhoneNumer.innerHTML = item["contact_number"];
                Active.innerHTML = item["is_active"];
            })
        },
        error: function (req, status, errorObj) {
            alert(errorObj.toString());
        }
    });
```

How to I store the `data` in `$.each(data, function (index, item)` as TEMPORARY table or (store it in a variable as JSON) for later use?

i tried this on AJAX calls:

```
    success: function (data) {
                tempTable = data;
     }
```

But `tempTable` is equal to undefined;
I was gonna use the `tempTable` for later user such as sending it to a controller when the user clicks on a certain button.

Comment: What sort of "later use" did you have in mind?

Comment: Without seeing more code it is hard to advise you. If the above is all the javascript you have, you can create a variable outside of the $.ajax call that will exist in the global scope. You could then use that later. It isn't recommended to pollute the global scope with a bunch of items like this, but it really depends on your use case.

Comment: I made some edit... I hope it would be helpful to answer :)

Comment: for what purpose you want to store data in json?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple options for storing temp data.

1. InMemory / In a variable outside the $.each :- So you would be doing something like this

```
var tempTable = [];
$.ajax(/*..*/).success(function(dataA){
  $.each(dataA, function(i, v){tempTable.push(v);})
});
```

In this case you will have tempTable populated after an ajax success call. So where ever you would want to use `tempTable` make sure it is used after the ajax call is complete.

2. In Html :- you can create a json of the returned object using `JSON.stringify(dataA`) and save it inside a hidden element. Or just use the $.data function to save the returned data associated with a DOM node. This way whenever you would want to use the data you will have to retrieve it from the HTML DOM. Have a look here https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/

3. In Cookies :- Saving the data in Cookies would enable you to use the data even after the browser window is closed and reopened again. You will have to manage the expiration of data and any change in its structure over lifetime of your application and will also have to code the casses in which user might have deleted the cookies. Saving the Data in cookies is easy have a look here https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

4. Local Storage :-  a relatively newer HTML5 tech. In which you can save data in the browser's local storage and everything about managing the state is of cookie is also applicable to managing the state of Local Storage. Have a look here http://www.jstorage.info/

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is  your purpose to store data for later use. But if I am correct and understood your question, you want to store retrieved JSON data in a variable and then later, you want to use it through loop. If this is what you want, I am proposing below solution which would work good for you:

```
   var tempTable = [];

   success: function (data) {
                tempTable = data;
     }
```

What it will do is will store your response in a variable which is type of array. Now you can loop on this `array` and can do anything you want to do (Anything means only you can perform operation which are supported for an `array`).

Hope this help. Let me know if you find any problem.

Comment: `tempTable`'s value is still `[]` after the ajax call

Comment: AND yes you really did understood my question :)

Comment: can you inspect the response you are getting from server. I suspect you getting null due to that reason.

Comment: Oh I am sorry, I didn't observed that. But it was for my curiosity too :D

Comment: But your solution worked if i put the data in the HTML element.. 
But it doesnt work if putting it in a js Variable

Comment: I can't predict but my guess would be absence of .ToList() on result being returned. Because I had this scenario in past and was working fine for me. So...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82772/discussion-between-simple-man-and-bienvenido-omosura).